# What exactly happens to large amplitude values when we load a .wav file using librosa?

Tags: python, audio, ipython, librosa, noise-reduction

I want to understand what happens to large amplitude values of a `.wav` file, when I load them using `librosa`.

I was trying to understand the amplitude values of `.wav` files when I see the waveform using `librosa`. Now, I want to see how scaling these values of amplitude affects the sound. Hence, I multiplied the values with a scaling factor. However, when I played that using `IPython.display.Audio`, I was not able to see any effect on the sound:

```
scaled_signal = signal * 10 # signal is the original sample

# play the scaled signal
print('Play the scaled sample:')
display(Audio(data = scaled_signal, rate = sr))
```

So I saved the file to my PC and I could hear the difference. The amplitude was indeed scaled. Then, I decided to reload this file using `librosa`. Surprisingly, now when I played this file again in my `jupyter-notebook`, I was able to hear the effect of scaling:

```
soundfile.write('scaled_signal.wav', scaled_signal, sr)

# loading the scaled signal again
scaled_signal, sr = librosa.load('scaled_signal.wav', sr = sr)

print('The scaled sample loaded again')
display(Audio(data = scaled_signal, rate = sr))
```

However, on plotting the waveform (see below) I could see that its shape has changed. Help me understand what happened and why? It appears as if it applied an upper_bound on magnitude of amplitudes.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_figwidth(18)

waveshow(signal, sr = sr, ax = axs[0])
waveshow(scaled_signal, sr = sr, ax = axs[1])
```

[The waveform of original signal and the scaled signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5MdY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`librosa.load()` does not apply any data-dependent normalization/scaling. Only mapping between int16/32 formats to a 0.0-1.0 range.

From the documentation for [IPython.display.Audio](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html), which you are using to play back the audio:

> If the array option is used the waveform will be normalized.

Comment: So does that mean, multiplication with the constant factor caused some values to overflow the maximum amplitude denoted by the particular int representation, and then it just applied a hardlimit on those values ?

Comment: The scaled signal shown in the plot is clipped. I would guess this happened on soundfile.write